# unixODBC + PHP , Invalid string or buffer length error message

Tags: php, ibm-midrange, unixodbc

I access to an AS400/DB2 with PHP via unixODBC
But some field name of my AS400 are named with "££.." (it can't be changed)
And when I tried to launch an sql query from my PHP page

```
select * from LIBNAME.TABLE where ££FIELD like 'test%'
```

I always get the same error message

> SQL error: [unixODBC][IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Invalid string or buffer length., SQL state S1090 in SQLExecDirect

If someone have clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this statement before the query execution:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US');
```

For a more detailed description of the issue: 
http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=3187

Answer (score 0):

DB2 should have some way of enclosing the identifiers.  Some databases use double quotes

```
select * from "tableID" where "fieldID" like 'blah%'
```

mySQL uses backticks.  Not sure with DB2 but shouldn't be too hard to find out and try.  If that doesn't work, see if there is a way to represent characters by hex value in a string.  Like 'hello\x0A\x0Dthere' would be the words 'hello' and 'there' separated by a line-break.  You may just need to find the value for £.